# Strange CMake behavior on Windows when attepmting to link the Qt/MSVC against the external dynamic library

Tags: c++, windows, qt, dll, cmake

I have experienced a painfull effort to make a Qt executable being built and linked against the dynamic library on Windows, which still more and more indicates some internal misbehavior inside the builder toolchain (Qt/CMake/MSVC). The problem description is as follows:

I have two major components:

1. My own portable library **TlvComms**, a Qt based project built using CMake
2. My own testbench exacutable **TestExec**, a Qt/QML based project built using CMake

All the code has been grown primarily on Linux (Ubuntu, CentOS) using Qt/CMake/gcc, it is fully tested and flawlesly working there. Now I am porting the code to Windows using Qt/CMake/MSVC, the set-up is as follows:

1. The **TlvComms** library has been built as an Windows dynamic library using Qt/CMake/MSVC toolchain with no significant problem, producing these distributables:

```
tlvcomms.dll
tlvcomms.lib
tlvcomms.exp
```

and

```
tlvcomms.h
tlvassy.h
```

These distributables were "installed" into special directories, let say `C:\usr\lib` and `C:\usr\include`, respectively. It went fully automated way with use of CMake's configure/build/install tools.

2. When attempting to build the testbench executable **TestExec** and link it against the above described **TlvComms** library with use of CMakeLists.txt as follows:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)

project(TestExec LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "C:/opt/Qt/5.15.2/msvc2019_64")
set(CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX "C:/usr")

find_package(Qt5 COMPONENTS Core Quick Gui Network REQUIRED)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME})

set(INC "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/include")
set(SRC "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/src")
set(RES "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/res")

#set(HDRS ${INC}/)
set(SRCS ${SRC}/main.cpp)
qt_add_resources(RESS ${RES}/main.qrc)

target_sources(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE
   #${HDRS}
   ${SRCS}
   ${RESS}
)

target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE ${SRC})
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE ${INC})
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE ${RES})

target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE "${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/include")

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE Qt5::Core Qt5::Gui Qt5::Quick Qt5::Network)

find_library(TLVCOMMS_LIB NAMES tlvcomms PATHS "${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/lib" NO_DEFAULT_PATH)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE ${TLVCOMMS_LIB})
```

and with TestExec main C++ code as follows:

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
// + other Qt includes

#include <tlvcomms.h> // +++
#include <tlvassy.h>  // +++

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
   QQmlApplicationEngine engine;

   CTlvSession session; // +++

   engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));

   int res = app.exec();
   return res;
}
```

... I fell into the unexpected troubles.

I expected the `TestExec.exe` executable being now built is going to be linked against the import library `tlvcomms.lib` which makes all exported library symbols available for later run-time linkage with their implementations in `tlvcomms.dll`. What really happened was surprising to me and ended-up with heavy two-week lasting horror with no reasonable outcome so far: **the CMake attempted to build a TestExec.lib instead of desired TestExec.exe ...** it is completely behind my understanding as there is no `add_library()` macro in the CMakeLists.txt, there is only `add_executable()` macro ... so why on the earth the CMake builds a library target?!

For the sake of completeness I append the CMake output of that:

```
D:\_usr\_projects\Product\TlvComms\tlvcomms\TestBench12>del /s /q com\*.* 
Deleted file - D:\_usr\_projects\Product\TlvComms\tlvcomms\TestBench12\com\.gitignore

D:\_usr\_projects\Product\TlvComms\tlvcomms\TestBench12>rmdir /s /q com\build64 

D:\_usr\_projects\Product\TlvComms\tlvcomms\TestBench12>copy null com/.gitignore 
The system cannot find the file specified.

D:\_usr\_projects\Product\TlvComms\tlvcomms\TestBench12>mkdir com\build64 

D:\_usr\_projects\Product\TlvComms\tlvcomms\TestBench12>cmake -G"Visual Studio 17 2022" -A x64 -B com\build64 
-- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.19041.0 to target Windows 10.0.19044.
-- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.30.30709.0
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.30.30705/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: D:/_usr/_projects/Product/TlvComms/tlvcomms/TestBench12/com/build64

D:\_usr\_projects\Product\TlvComms\tlvcomms\TestBench12>cmake --build com/build64 --config Release 
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 17.0.0+c9eb9dd64 for .NET Framework
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

  Checking Build System
  Automatic MOC and UIC for target TestExec
  Generating qrc_main.cpp
  Building Custom Rule D:/_usr/_projects/Product/TlvComms/tlvcomms/TestBench12/CMakeLists.txt
  main.cpp
  qrc_main.cpp
  mocs_compilation_Release.cpp
  Generating Code...
     Creating library D:/_usr/_projects/Product/TlvComms/tlvcomms/TestBench12/com/build64/Release/TestExec.lib and object D:/_usr/_projects/Product/TlvComms/tlvcomms/TestBench12/com/build64/Release/TestExec.exp
main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static struct QMetaObject const CTlvComms::staticMetaObject" (?staticMetaObject@CTlvComms@@2UQMetaObject@@B) referenced in function "public: static class QString __cdecl CTlvComms::tr(char const *,char const *,int)" (?tr@CTlvComms@@SA?AVQString@@PEBD0H@Z) [D:\_usr\_projects\Product\TlvComms\tlvcomms\TestBench12\com\build64\TestExec.vcxproj]
D:\_usr\_projects\Product\TlvComms\tlvcomms\TestBench12\com\build64\Release\TestExec.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals [D:\_usr\_projects\Product\TlvComms\tlvcomms\TestBench12\com\build64\TestExec.vcxproj]

D:\_usr\_projects\Product\TlvComms\tlvcomms\TestBench12>rem windeployqt --qmldir src com\build64\src\Release
```

To make it even worse, when I comment-out all references to my TlvComms library symbols from the TestExec main.cpp (the lines marked with +++), everything goes well and CMake builds standard TestExec.exe, which I can run (opens a window with some buttons) and close flawlesly - **all that with making no changes to the CMakeLists.txt, just by eliminating the library symbols from the application code at the C++ level!** You can see that on following CMake output:

```
D:\_usr\_projects\Product\TlvComms\tlvcomms\TestBench12>del /s /q com\*.* 
Deleted file - D:\_usr\_projects\Product\TlvComms\tlvcomms\TestBench12\com\.gitignore

D:\_usr\_projects\Product\TlvComms\tlvcomms\TestBench12>rmdir /s /q com\build64 

D:\_usr\_projects\Product\TlvComms\tlvcomms\TestBench12>copy null com/.gitignore 
The system cannot find the file specified.

D:\_usr\_projects\Product\TlvComms\tlvcomms\TestBench12>mkdir com\build64 

D:\_usr\_projects\Product\TlvComms\tlvcomms\TestBench12>cmake -G"Visual Studio 17 2022" -A x64 -B com\build64 
-- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.19041.0 to target Windows 10.0.19044.
-- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.30.30709.0
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.30.30705/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: D:/_usr/_projects/Product/TlvComms/tlvcomms/TestBench12/com/build64

D:\_usr\_projects\Product\TlvComms\tlvcomms\TestBench12>cmake --build com/build64 --config Release 
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 17.0.0+c9eb9dd64 for .NET Framework
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

  Checking Build System
  Automatic MOC and UIC for target TestExec
  Generating qrc_main.cpp
  Building Custom Rule D:/_usr/_projects/Product/TlvComms/tlvcomms/TestBench12/CMakeLists.txt
  main.cpp
  qrc_main.cpp
  mocs_compilation_Release.cpp
  Generating Code...
  TestExec.vcxproj -> D:\_usr\_projects\Product\TlvComms\tlvcomms\TestBench12\com\build64\Release\TestExec.exe
  Building Custom Rule D:/_usr/_projects/Product/TlvComms/tlvcomms/TestBench12/CMakeLists.txt

D:\_usr\_projects\Product\TlvComms\tlvcomms\TestBench12>rem windeployqt --qmldir src com\build64\src\Release
```

Any suggestion or hint is highly appreciated, I am perhaps blind to some detail I completely missed in my project set-up, I don't believe this is to be a standard CMake performance ... Thank you very much!

Comment: What's the value of `${TLVCOMMS_LIB}`? Is the tlv library built with the same version of visual studio and the same runtime library type? Have you tried opening the generated vs projects to see what the linker commands are?

Comment: @AlanBirtles Thank you Alan for the points: 1. message(${TLVCOMMS_LIB}) shows C:/usr/lib/tlvcomms.lib, so I guess the library is properly detected by CMake 2. Yes, I have the only dev machine where all tests happened, so versions of Qt/CMake/MSVC are all the same for both library and executable, although the two projects are kept strictly isolated (intentionally), I mean the CMake running on the executable has no chance to sniff to library's CMakeLists.txt, the two projects are intended to be built separately 3. I havent a I will-) That may reveal what linker really gets from CMake ... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is no Qt problem but the default windows behavior - every symbol in a shared library is hidden by default (in contrast to linux where everything is visible). You have to add the proper export macros as described e.g. [here](https://wiki.qt.io/How_to_create_a_library_with_Qt_and_use_it_in_an_application) (Creating a shared library, use add_target_defintions(foo PRIVATE MAKE_TEST_LIB) for cmake)

Comment: Sorry @chehrlic, I have to disagree. I have meticulously exported all needed library symbols using the Q_DECL_EXPORT macro and I can easily check it out using utilities for COFF analyse (e.g. dumpbin.exe), which clearly shows my library symbols exported. Moreover, the Qt/CMake/MSVC toolchain even will not produce any output (no .dll/.lib/.exp) until it find at least one symbol exported with Q_DECL_EXPORT... I guess I have my .dll/.lib/.exp built proper way, but the probelm occurs when I want to link a Windows executable agianst that library, the CMake produces another library ...

Comment: Anyhow, thank you very much for your reply and for nice Qt Wiki page on creating libraries. Thank you.